# Bar chart with Trellis--How to remove categories that are filtered?

Tags: spotfire, trellis

[image: [Screenshot]

The question is regarding the top bar chart.

I used Trellis tab in Properties to divide among AL and NL. As you can see, the values of the team that belong to the other league were filtered, and yet there still is an empty space allotted for the filtered columns. How to I remove the filtered columns, and display only the categories that are relevant?

So basically I do not want any empty spaces for each AL and NL chart.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Trellis works. If you want them completely separated create two separate bar charts and limit the data using expressions, or apply a custom filtering scheme. The first option is the simplest and is my preferred method.

- Right Click > Properties > Data > Limit Data Using Expressions > Edit
- Expression: `[leagueColumn] = 'AL'` or if you want to be explicit, yet have the same effect, `if([leagueColumn] = 'AL', TRUE, FALSE)`

Do this for the other chart, using `NL` as well.